# How To Convert MongoDB Query To Mysql In Node

Tags: javascript, mysql, mongodb

I want to convert mongoDB to mysql in my app. My app was built by node.js
But I have an issue with "Create table" query.
Here is my code.

```
var setting = new MongoCon.Schema({
site: {
    type: Object,
    default: {
        someData: {
            lengthMsgBc: 250,
            likeUpPic: 10,
        },
        title: "",
        walllikes: {
            likeUpPic: 10,
        },
    },
},
dro3: {
    type: Array,
    default: [
        "1604251747557.gif",
        "1604251842627.gif",
        "1604251846871.gif",
    ],
},
});
```

Here is the converted query to sql.

```
mysqlCon.query('CREATE TABLE al3ochek_settings (_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, site VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT "{"someData":{"lengthMsgBc":250,"likeUpPic":10},"title":"","walllikes":{"likeUpPic":10}}", dro3 VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT "["1604251747557.gif","1604251842627.gif","1604251846871.gif"]", PRIMARY KEY (_id) )', err => {
if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Table al3ochek_settings created!")
})
```

This SQL query has an error.
If I do JSON.stringify to save an object to the "site" column.
It returns an error.
Because of this string.

```
"{"  "["
```

How can I solve it?
If you have a solution please help me and I will be appreciated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use different kind of quote for your query, since you used both single and double quote, you can put the whole query between back ticks like that:

```
`CREATE TABLE al3ochek_settings (_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, site VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '{"someData":{"lengthMsgBc":250,"likeUpPic":10},"title":"","walllikes":{"likeUpPic":10}}", dro3 VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT "["1604251747557.gif","1604251842627.gif","1604251846871.gif"]', PRIMARY KEY (_id) )`
```